# Passing variable from one php file to another

Tags: php, html, get

So after my php script is done I have this line:

```
$success = TRUE;
header('Location: ../admin.php'); //the main file
```

In the admin.php file I have this line:

```
<?php

    if ($_GET["success"] == TRUE) {
        echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>";
    }
```

Any idea why this boolean isn't being passed through and why the echo is not working?

Comment: Who said that `header()` is sending  `$_GET` information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your variable in the url like this:

```
header("Location: ../admin.php?success=$success");
     //^                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So that on the next page you can access it via `$_GET`. Also note that I used double quotes here, so that the variable in the string gets parsed as variable.

Comment: so just so I am clear there is no other way to transferring values from one php file to another php file? For example, lets say this wasn't even a form. What if I have a simple php file that has $test = "abc" and you want to get the value of $test in another php file?

Comment: @user3645858 Yes there is, I think you are looking for the `$_SESSION` array. You have to start your session on every page which you want to use it with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php and then you can access variables in `$_SESSION` over other pages

Comment: Ah right totally forgot about $_SESSION. Thanks for clearing this up. Ur a god